# Enviar mensaje a un usuario en especifico en nodejs socket.io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Saludos, como podría hacer para que un mensaje solo llegue a un usuario en especifico, porque utilizando io.sockets.emit hace que el mensaje le llegue a todos pero no he podido hacer que llegue solo a un usuario que seleccione, si me pudieran orientar se lo agradecería.

Comment: Hola Teresa. Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado y por que te ha fallad? Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
io.to(socketid).emit('message', 'Este mensaje es único para un usuario');
```

El `socketid` es el identificador de cada uno de los clientes conectados a tu servidor (Hay que tener en cuenta que un mismo usuario puede abrir 3 ventanas del navegador, y esto serían 3 clientes diferentes).

Puedes, por ejemplo, crearte un array de socketid's e incluso relacionar el socketid de la conexión con el de un usuario loggeado de tu aplicación si hiciera falta. De esta forma podrías distinguirlo y saber quien es en cualquier momento.

Espero te sirva de ayuda!

Comment: Muchas gracias por responderme como podría, me podrías dar un ejemplo de como relacionar el socketid de la conexión con el de un usuario logeado?

Comment: Eso está bien para pocos usuarios, pero si tienes a miles conectados a la vez quizá te dé un problema de memoria :o

Comment: Sin duda  @J.Correa ! Además de que no es escalable horizontalmente. Lo comenté como opción ya que ayuda a entender como identificar un usuario logado con su socket. Pero si, estoy contigo que no es una opción práctica para una puesta en producción por los problemas de escalabilidad y de memoria. Yo suelo utilizar Redis para mis aplicaciones con sockets.

Answer (score 0):

No me llevo muy bien con socket, pero te voy a comentar cual fue mi método para poder lograr enviar datos a un socket en especifico, cada vez que hay una nueva conexion se genera un id del socket, en el momento que hay una nueva conexion yo guardo ese id en una base de datos de esta manera

```
const { usuarios } = require('./models');

// Server is listening
   const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
   console.log('Server on port', app.get('port'));
   console.log('Environment:', process.env.NODE_ENV);
   });

   app.use((req, res, next) => {
       res.locals.user = req.user || null;
      next();
    });

   socketIo(server).on('connect', async (socket)=>{

    var id = await usuarios.findOneAndUpdate({_id: user._id {SocketId: socket.id}})

   })
```

Como ves, cuando hay una nueva conexion, lo que hago es guarda ese id en la base de datos, en ocaciones puedes crear un objeto y guardar los id en ese objeto pero no es muy recomendable por problemas de escalabilidad

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
io.sockets.emit('play:getSaludo', { 'mensaje': "Buenos dias a todos" });
```

Manda a todos

```javascript
io.to(socket.id).emit('play:getSaludo', { 'mensaje': "Buenos dias Pepito" });
```

Manda al usuario que hace la petición